# Oracle sql with subqueries causing peformance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Writing oracle sql with 3 subqueries, however it is causing a timeout issue. Hoping for technical help on getting to the fix.  Here is my query:

```
select   DISTINCT E_reg.applicant_id,
             E_REG.L_NAME, 
             E_REG.F_NAME, 
             E_REG.B_DATE,
            E_REG.REG_DATE,
 from     E_REG,TRANSACTION
where   E_REG.ID=TRANSACTION.PAR_ID
  and       TRANSACTION.BEGIN_DATE BETWEEN to_date ('01-APR-2012')AND to_date('30-JUN-               2012')
and  e_reg.applicant_id NOT IN
              (select applicant_id
                   from w_reg
                  where reg_date <'01-JUL-2012' 
                   and exit_date is NULL or exit_date >='01-APR-2012'
or  e_reg.applicant_id NOT IN
              (select applicant_id
                   from t_reg
                  where reg_date <'01-JUL-2012' 
                   and exit_date is NULL or exit_date>='01-APR-2012')
or  e_reg.applicant_id NOT IN
              (select applicant_id
                   from r_reg
                  where reg_date <'01-JUL-2012' 
                     and o_attend IS NOT NULL
                   and term_date is NULL or term_date >='01-APR-2012')
```

Basically we have 4 programs that you can be in ( e, w, t, and r).  Those are all seperate tables that house basic participant information.  You may be in all 4 programs at the same time, the applicant_id will be the key for everyone.

The transaction table house any service you may receive in that 3 or the 4 programs, not the r program, that has its own transaction table.

I want a listing of participants in e table that had a service in the timeframe but did not have any services in any of the other programs at the same time.  They would be only serviced though the e program.  It seemed to work this morning but then it starting timing out and not running at all.  I figure it must be the subquery. Wondering if there is a better way to make this work.

Comment: and the explain plan for this looks like what?  If you can provide a SQL fiddle people will be more inclined to help.

Comment: This looks like it is doing full table scans every time, which may be a bottle neck.

Comment: please post query execution plan and table definitions with indexes and preferably with row count estimates for each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is parentheses in your `where` clause.  You have `or` clauses that are undoing the join.  If you always use ANSI join syntax, you greatly reduce the possibility of this occurring.

Here is the alternative version:

```
select   DISTINCT E_reg.applicant_id,
             E_REG.L_NAME, 
             E_REG.F_NAME, 
             E_REG.B_DATE,
            E_REG.REG_DATE,
 from    E_REG join
         TRANSACTION
         on E_REG.ID=TRANSACTION.PAR_ID
  where TRANSACTION.BEGIN_DATE BETWEEN to_date ('01-APR-2012')AND to_date('30-JUN-               2012')
and  (e_reg.applicant_id NOT IN
              (select applicant_id
                   from w_reg
                  where reg_date <'01-JUL-2012' 
                   and exit_date is NULL or exit_date >='01-APR-2012'
or  e_reg.applicant_id NOT IN
              (select applicant_id
                   from t_reg
                  where reg_date <'01-JUL-2012' 
                   and exit_date is NULL or exit_date>='01-APR-2012')
or  e_reg.applicant_id NOT IN
              (select applicant_id
                   from r_reg
                  where reg_date <'01-JUL-2012' 
                     and o_attend IS NOT NULL
                   and term_date is NULL or term_date >='01-APR-2012')
   )
```

Comment: I took out the "or" and replaced with "and" and adjusted the join syntax.  Thanks!